# RDF "Description" v.s. OWL "NamedIndividual"

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, protege

I have an ontology in Protege 5, I save it as RDF/XML and it makes this format:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://namespace.name/motivate">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://namespace.name/#motivationLanguage"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

When I Use JENA API to try and generate new instances in RDF I get:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://namespace.name/motivate">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual"/>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://namespace.name/#motivationLanguage"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

Why is one called "NamedIndividual" and one is "Description", JENA not OWL compatible? if not, what lib can I use to make instances like the first one? Thanks.

Comment: both are the semantically the same, just a different RDF/XML serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jena is using RDF/XML, Protégé is using RDF-XML-ABBREV. The two variants are equivalent and both frameworks will accept either as input. The ABBREV version uses some syntactic shortcuts, nothing else.

Comment: Can I expect programs like Stardog and graphDB to work and reason over this if I import  ontology and data files of both types?

Comment: I expect so - I don't have copies to test but I've not met any library which did not cope with both languages.